# ¿Como leer Json desde un archivo en Java con libreria JSON Simple?

Tags: java, json

Tengo el siguiente código que me arroja un error en tiempo de ejecución y no sé donde está el problema:

EL ERROR:

> Excepcion leyendo fichero de configuracion java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be
>   cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

Mi código:

```
 public static void readJson(){


    try {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/incentivate/Desktop/config.cfg"));

        for (Object object : jsonArray)
        {
          JSONObject config = (JSONObject) object;

          String verb = (String) config.get("verb");
          System.out.println(verb);

          String host = (String) config.get("host");
          System.out.println(host);

          String port = (String) config.get("port");
          System.out.println(port);

          String method = (String) config.get("method");
          System.out.println(method);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Excepcion leyendo fichero de configuracion " + e);
    }

}
```

Así se ve mi config.cfg por si lo necesitan:

```
{"verb"  :"POST",
 "host"  :"192.169.3.243",
 "port"  :"8080",
 "method":"API/DOCUMENTS/"}
```

Lo que necesito es obtener cada valor del JSON dentro de una variable JAVA para luego poder seguir usandolas.

Estoy usando Java 8 y la librería JSON Simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error indica que el tipo que se esta leyendo es en realidad un JSONObject no un JSONArray. Por lo que debe bastar con poner:

```
public static void readJson(){
      try {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object object =  parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/incentivate/Desktop/config.cfg"));


          JSONObject config = (JSONObject) object;

          String verb = (String) config.get("verb");
          System.out.println(verb);

          String host = (String) config.get("host");
          System.out.println(host);

          String port = (String) config.get("port");
          System.out.println(port);

          String method = (String) config.get("method");
          System.out.println(method);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Excepcion leyendo fichero de configuracion " + e);
    }
   }
```

Como tu archivo de configuración tiene solo un elemento con varias propiedades no es necesario un JSONArray.